# How to localize DatePicker's date format based on the language defined in Regional settings

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I've an English windows 7 installed on my machine and the default language chosen is English (using "Regional and language settings"). When I read the `DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern` using the following C# statement:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```

I got this result

```
"M/d/yyyy"
```

I also tried this statement, and still got the same string.

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern  
"M/d/yyyy"
```

However, now I changed the language from "Regional and language settings" and chose Danish language. Now if I switched to Format tab and under short date format it shows `"M/d/åååå"` which is localized to Danish language. This means that by changing the language the date time format also changes.

However, in my application I still get the above English format string even though the loaded CurrentUICulture is correct i.e da-DK for Danish. I want to display the localized ShortDateFormat as is shown in Regional settings. Do I need to do the localization myself or is there any build in way to do that. Please let me know if I am missing something here.

Edit:This information is added to further clarify the question based on the discussion with Peter.

The Format combobox say Danish(Denmark). The format is read fine i.e Danish but the string still says M/d/yyyy instead of M/d/åååå. This is the exact string M/d/åååå that I want to display in my DatePicker control. In other words the watermark should display the localized ShortDatePattern. Still struggling...

Answer (score 1):

Try setting CurrentCulture, not CurrentUICulture. For example:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
```

CurrentUICulture specifies the resources an application needs.

CultureInfo specifies the default format for dates, times, numbers, currency values, the sorting order of text, casing conventions, and string comparisons and is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but what would you expect the outcome of the following statement after the above statement?

  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern  

  the outcome is "dd-MM-yyyy" which is still an english string not a danish like this "dd-MM-åååå".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C# example of what you can do. (Dump is a linqpad extension method which you can ignore in your own code).

A full list of date format string is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
var languages =  new List<string>{"de-DE", "en", "es-ES", "es-MX", "fr-FR", "it-IT", "pt-BR", "sv-SE"};
    var date = DateTime.Now;
    languages.Select (l => new {
        Lang=l,

        d_shortDate =  date.ToString("d", new CultureInfo(l)),
        D_longDate =  date.ToString("D", new CultureInfo(l)),
        g_generalDate1 =  date.ToString("g", new CultureInfo(l)),
        m =  date.ToString("m", new CultureInfo(l)),
        y =  date.ToString("y", new CultureInfo(l)),
        dd = date.ToString("dd", new CultureInfo(l)),
        mm = date.ToString("mm", new CultureInfo(l)),
        yy = date.ToString("yy", new CultureInfo(l)),
    }) .Dump();
```

[image: Date formats]